# Webhook for tomcat logs

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, webhooks

I understand that a webhook alerts the client whenever an event occurs. I was wondering if we can create one for tomcat logs; probably when an error gets logged.

Is there a way I can do it? I tried googling, but haven't been much successful. Maybe I am not using the right set of search keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. 
https://github.com/tobias-/slack-appender.

Steps to follow:

1. Create a slack channel where the logs would be posted.
2. Create an app in slack and enable incoming webhooks. Point to the above mentioned channel.
3. Use the jars from the above mentioned github project and place in the classpath.
4. modify log4j.properties to include slack as one of the appenders.

Voila, all the needed logs are posted to my slack channel.